# TYPO3: How to use flux:field.inline.fal image as background

Tags: typo3, flux, fluid, view-helpers

In a template in my extension I use the **field.inline.fal** viewhelper: [Documentation](https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/flux/master/Field/Inline/FalViewHelper.html)

Now I want to use this as a background image. I tried:

```
// This is the input in the configuration section
<flux:field.inline.fal name="image" required="1" maxItems="1" minItems="1"/>

//This is the output
{v:content.resources.fal(field: 'image') -> v:iterator.first() -> v:variable.set(name: 'image')}
<div class="image" style="background: url({image.id});">
```

For some reason the frontend output is:

```
<div class="image" style="background: url(1:/data/images/path/image.jpg);">
```

but it should be

```
<div class="image" style="background: url(/rootfolder/data/images/path/image.jpg);">
```

Why doesn't it display as described in the Documentation? What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer.
Via <f:debug>{image} I found the variable {image.url} which gives the whole path.

Working code:

```
  <div class="image" style="background: url(/{image.url});">
```